# PowerBI, visual total not matching individual row total

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to PowerBI. I have a couple of questions.

1. The primary question relates to visual totals. I am aware why visual totals would not match individual row sum (measure calculation is applied to the context of the total). I am trying to figure out how to resolve this mismatch.

[image]

You would see that "Value" total does not match individual row sum. Below are the measures / calculated columns used:

```
Value = ([Balance] + sumx(Txns,[Quantity] * max(Securities[LatestValuation]))) * max(Ownership[Ownership_%])

Quantity = Sum(Txns[Qty])

LatestValuation (Calculated Column) = 
VAR LatestDate = CALCULATE(max(Pricing[ValuationDate]))
RETURN CALCULATE(MAX(Pricing[ValuePerUnit]),Pricing[ValuationDate]=LatestDate)
```

Here are the relationships to help understand table structure better:

[image]

2. While I am using LatestValuation as a calculated column, would it be possible to use it as a measure to extract the latest value under the current context from the Pricing table? I have tried doing it, but haven't been able to fetch the correct values.

Thanks!

Comment: Which of these are measures and which calculated columns, and for the calculated columns what table are they on (for measures it doesn't matter)?  And what tables do the fields in the Matrix come from?

Comment: Measures: Balance, Quantity and Value; Calculated Column: Latest Valuation which belongs to the table Pricing.

Comment: In the matrix: EntityCode comes from Entities (Dimension table), InvestmentName comes from Securities (Dimension table), Ownership % comes from Ownership (Fact table). Rest are measures. To be clear, only bothered about the total of value field and not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice to have a sample data table/tables. for now you can test the following. Please, let me know if it helps.

```
sumx(
     Txns
     ,SumX(
          Values(Pricing[InvestmentName])
          ,[Quantity] * CALCULATE(max(Securities[LatestValuation]))
     )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked after replacing Pricing[InvestmentName] with Securities[InvestmentName].